# Lanterna how do I change the font size?

Tags: java, lanterna

I've been trying for 3 days now to change the font size in Laterna because it's so small in the console that it's unreadable. In the API I can only get:

`SwingTerminalFontConfiguration.newinstance(....);`

So I tried to use (new Font) but it didn't change. I need help, if you can help me please send me an example script to explain it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Font myFont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20); // Change the number 20 to your desired font size
            AWTTerminalFontConfiguration myFontConfiguration = AWTTerminalFontConfiguration.newInstance(myFont);
            // Use myFontConfiguration when creating your terminal
            // Create a default terminal (will use Swing on desktop)
            // Use myFontConfiguration when creating your terminal
            DefaultTerminalFactory dtf = new DefaultTerminalFactory();
            dtf.setForceAWTOverSwing(true);
            dtf.setTerminalEmulatorFontConfiguration(myFontConfiguration);
            Terminal terminal = dtf.createTerminal();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).